# Go - Regex operations

Tags: regex, go

My string is :

```
First Name: ABCD
```

I want following string to be captured.

```
ABCD
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: (ABCD) ............

Comment: but ABCD can be anything. its name it can vary

Answer (score 3):

I think what you need is [Regexp.FindAllString](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllString)